# How to compile clover(code coverage tool from atlassian)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clover

clover is now open source source available here how to compile it locally and use it with eclipse

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/clover

there are multiple projects like clover-core, clover-eclipse please tell me which project will i needed to compile locally and use clover in eclipse

[screenshot of list of projects downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQjr6.png)

can anyone please help in compiling and provide me clover jar

Comment: How about taking a look at the build.xml file? I think there are even maven files included (any why not simply use jacoco/eclemma with eclipse? ;)

Comment: jacoco/eclemma is not working with powermock it doesnt show any coverage when i use powermock to mock static calls and mock final class.if you know any other tools that can show coverage with powermock please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Clover as an Eclipse plugin you'll need to compile clover-eclipse module. It uses internally clover-core so it should be compiled prior it, however ANT should handle this dependency well. Atlassian published official development [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/clover-core-ant-eclipse-and-idea-plugins-developer-guide-858560682.html) describing how to compile Clover, you might want to take a look at it.